# Add background shape to the camera screen

Tags: java, android, camera

I found a code that opens the camera once I click the button "camera".
The app let me take a picture and save it to the gallery.

However, I want to add an image to the center of the screen (for example a rectangle) so I could know where is the middle of my screen whenever I take a picture.

The code looks like this:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.camera.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button b1,b2;
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView android:text="Camera Example" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tutorials point"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ff7aff24"
    android:textSize="35dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="camera"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your current implementation, you are capturing images using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. The intent is sent to the camera application to capture an image and return it. 
Hence, the image capture screen is not within your app. And so you will not be able to add any view to it.

For your requirement, you will have to implement your own camera. Check out the section '[Building a Camera App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)'. Then you will be able to add whatever views you want to it.